# Merry X-mas and happy New Year

Tags: discussion

As it's been almost 2 years of incredible bad times for everybody and the whole planet, I wish this community and everyone a much better time during this holiday season!

Please take care of yourself, of your beloved ones and of all others if and when you can.

Enjoy these little moments, hug, kiss, cuddle, smile, laugh whenever it's possible.

You can also wear one of these lovely hats you can find around here, it'll perfectly fit with the wonderful sweater grandma knitted for you or that your pals bought for you as a poisoned gift :)

Happy holidays to all of you, here's some human (or not ^^) warmth to cheer you up !

**And all the best for now and the upcoming years...**

---

<sup>As I had to choose a tag, I picked [discussion](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) so you can share your thoughts and experience ;)</sup>